# microk8s in docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, microk8s

For the automatic testing of my code I would like to add a `microk8s` in my docker-compose setup for testing. Hence, I'd like to install microk8s in docker environment

I got snap running in the docker container using the following commands from the [web](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-in-docker/177/13)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV container docker
ENV PATH /snap/bin:$PATH
ADD snap /usr/local/bin/snap
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y snapd squashfuse fuse
RUN systemctl enable snapd
STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3
CMD [ "/sbin/init" ]
```

snap script

```
!/bin/sh -e

while ! kill -0 $(pidof snapd) 2>/dev/null; do
  echo "Waiting for snapd to start."
  sleep 1
done

/usr/bin/snap $@
```

and building docker

```
docker build -t snapd .
```

and run

```
 docker run --name=snapd -ti -d --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp --privileged -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro snapd
```

up to here everything is fine.

However if try to install microk8s via snap it fails

```
snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.18/stable
2020-04-27T14:22:39Z INFO Waiting for restart...
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run install hook of "microk8s" snap if present (run hook "install": execv failed: Permission denied)
```

checking snap `systemctl status snapd.service` gives me

```
Apr 27 15:14:32 8985fc7fc5cb snapd[489]: helpers.go:961: cannot retrieve info for snap "microk8s": cannot find installed snap "microk8s" at revision 1341: missing file /sn
ap/microk8s/1341/meta/snap.yaml
Apr 27 15:14:33 8985fc7fc5cb snapd[489]: helpers.go:105: error trying to compare the snap system key: system-key versions not comparable
Apr 27 15:14:33 8985fc7fc5cb snapd[489]: helpers.go:961: cannot retrieve info for snap "microk8s": cannot find installed snap "microk8s" at revision 1341: missing file /sn
ap/microk8s/1341/meta/snap.yaml
Apr 27 15:14:33 8985fc7fc5cb systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Apr 27 15:15:08 8985fc7fc5cb snapd[489]: handlers.go:495: Reported install problem for "microk8s" as e11fe0c4-8899-11ea-a8e2-fa163ee63de6 OOPSID
```

Comment: You might look into [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) but in general running something like this inside a container is difficult.  (`systemctl` is one of a couple of things that broadly just doesn’t work in Docker and usually you’d want to restructure things to avoid needing an init system and especially systemd.)

Comment: @DavidMaze hence the only way is a (k)vm? this is annoying.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I also added you recommendation with kind as one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

I found a (for me) somewhat satisfying answer is to use k3s
[A German description can be found here](https://www.trion.de/news/2019/08/28/kubernetes-in-docker-mit-k3s.html)

The key is the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: rancher/k3s:v0.8.1
    command: server --disable-agent
    environment:
    - K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom
    - K3S_KUBECONFIG_OUTPUT=/output/kubeconfig.yaml
    - K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=666
    volumes:
    - k3s-server:/var/lib/rancher/k3s
    # get the kubeconfig file
    - .:/output
    ports:
    - 6443:6443

  node:
    image: rancher/k3s:v0.8.1
    tmpfs:
    - /run
    - /var/run
    privileged: true
    environment:
    - K3S_URL=https://server:6443
    - K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom
    ports:
      - 31000-32000:31000-32000

  worker:
    image: rancher/k3s:v0.8.1
    tmpfs:
    - /run
    - /var/run
    privileged: true
    environment:
    - K3S_URL=https://server:6443
    - K3S_CLUSTER_SECRET=somethingtotallyrandom

volumes:
  k3s-server: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just for completeness but I don't accept this answer, if so it my own but suggested by @David Maze) You can use `kind` Kubernetes in Docker. it was primarily developed for testing docker itself.

Comment: The reason I (personally) don't like this answer is that my final system will be micork8s based.

Comment: the other thing I didn't like was that I have to install go as additional requirement